# Cufon for Microsoft's fonts

Tags: fonts

Anyone know where I can find info about which Microsoft fonts I can use with Cufon for my websites? (for free, of course).

Ideally, I would like to use one of the following:

Calibri
Corbel
Segoi UI
Tahoma
Verdana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a complex matter. If you were just using css to specify the font to render in the users machine, it'd make the browser render a font already present in the user machine, so, no issues. But Cufon seems to be actually converting the design to a vectorial shape, and making it available to every browser through a conversion to javascript. This would be actually using the design physically,(even if not using the ttf file) which might have been registered as a design. There's controversy though, in the case of fonts.
These fonts seem not to be totally free for every use, also. They've made them available for certain free uses for Powerpoint viewers, Office applications, etc.  But I'd check on each font's license to know what is allowed.

The other way is simply use in css alternative ok looking fonts, and set these as optional, in the order you prefer. This, instead of embedding.